# MonoDevelop Google API GData assembly not found

Tags: google, monodevelop

I'd like to create an application that can communicate with my spreadsheets with google documents.

I've installed `MonoDevelop 2.6` and I've `libgdata1.7-cil` **(Google's API for C#)** installed on my computer.

Now, when I start a new project with MonoDevelop, I'm seeking for a reference assembly that would look like Google.GData or something like that, but I just can't find it...

Should I seek it manually inside my computer or am I missing something?

Thank you for your tips...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found the problem, the `libgdata1.7-cil` is for the applications to work without the assembly useful for the development.

To be able to create an application that uses Google's API for C#, you need to download the `libgdata-cil-dev`, that you can find with synaptic.